# Some trouble with mounts

Tags: linux-mint, mount

I have some trouble with my disk setup here.

Basically I recently reformatted my windows disk and wanted to add it's space in.
Therefore I divided the disk into 3 partitions and mounted them into my `~/`

here is the fstab part:

```
UUID=d8e94b7d-3de9-4cee-9ce6-1040e5e2f534 /                         ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
UUID=8410facb-a994-4cb8-95c1-20b46ede42cd /home/ckoenig/Coding      ext4    defaults          0       2
UUID=d81dc162-6a4b-4715-9652-8dff3d2f42d9 /home/ckoenig/Docs        ext4    defaults          0       2
UUID=7ce2081c-94a0-456f-84c9-43b27b2bb7d4 /home/ckoenig/Games       ext4    defaults          0       2
```

The first strange thing is that **GParted** complains about two of those:

[image]

the warning is basically this:

> Der Inhalt des Dateisystems konnte nicht gelesen werden! Aufgrund
>   dessen könnten einige Vorgänge nicht zur Verfügung stehen. Die Ursache
>   könnte ein fehlendes Softwarepaket sein. Die folgende Liste zeigt die
>   Softwarepakete, die zur Unterstützung des ext4-Dateisystems
>   erforderlich sind: e2fsprogs v1.41+.

Sorry about the german - it says that the content could not be read and it tells me to get `e2fsprogs` (which I of course have)

The second strang thing is that `df` tells me the `dev` correctly but will always show the same blocks and stuff:

```
ckoenig@CarstenLinuxMint ~ $ df /
Dateisystem                                            1K-Blöcke   Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/disk/by-uuid/d8e94b7d-3de9-4cee-9ce6-1040e5e2f534 237318840 120627816 104612844   54% /
ckoenig@CarstenLinuxMint ~ $ df /home/ckoenig
Dateisystem            1K-Blöcke   Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/home/ckoenig/.Private 237318840 120627816 104612844   54% /home/ckoenig
ckoenig@CarstenLinuxMint ~ $ df /home/ckoenig/Coding/
Dateisystem    1K-Blöcke   Benutzt Verfügbar Verw% Eingehängt auf
/dev/sda1      237318840 120627816 104612844   54% /home/ckoenig/Coding
```

`df` alone will not show `/dev/sda`at all.

Now I think that obviously the data will still end up on the one disk and I am kindof lost here ... any guesses?

---

in case it's important - here are the parts that should matter:

```
> sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Coding" UUID="8410facb-a994-4cb8-95c1-20b46ede42cd" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Docs" UUID="d81dc162-6a4b-4715-9652-8dff3d2f42d9" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Games" UUID="7ce2081c-94a0-456f-84c9-43b27b2bb7d4" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc1: UUID="D540-BADF" TYPE="vfat" 
/dev/sdc2: UUID="d8e94b7d-3de9-4cee-9ce6-1040e5e2f534" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sdc3: UUID="b6eff8d4-58ba-4a88-bc3f-1c191d7aac4d" TYPE="swap"
```

---

```
> /dev $ grep /dev/sd. /proc/mounts

/dev/sdb1 /mnt/88E44C6DE44C5F94 fuseblk rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096 0 0
/dev/sda1 /home/ckoenig/Coding ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda2 /home/ckoenig/Docs ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sda3 /home/ckoenig/Games ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /boot/efi vfat rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```

Comment: Just for clarity, what does `sudo LC_ALL=C mount /dev/sda2` output?

Comment: @muru: `mount: mount point output does not exist` :(

Comment: And for the other one? `sda1`?

Comment: btw: in case you think `/dev/sda2` is not mounted because the block is all white: if I make the window larger it will show similar stuff as the others

Comment: same - and for `sda3` too ... but isn't that to be expected?

Comment: btw: there is no way that on `/dev/sda3` is so much stuff present - it should be basically empty (just downloading a stream game to it)

Comment: Please post output of `grep /dev/sd. /proc/mounts`

Comment: @Otheus done .. sorry for the delay - was AFK eating

Comment: Somehow `/dev/sdc2` is nout mounted. That means `/` is not mounted. How is this possible? But `df` showed that it is mounted. You could see this scenario if `/` were mounted _after_ `/dev/sda*`. Then these would be mounted, but "underneath" the current `/home` tree, and thus not accessible. But that can't be what's going on here. 

To answer another question: it's possible that the partition table was changed but that the kernel still has an older view of it. A reboot will fix this, but I recommend you boot into recovery mode and stepwise mount each partition.

Comment: oh I rebooted quite a few time since (it's easily a few weeks since I changed it and I shutdown my PC if I don't need it) - also I'm quite sure that the root is mounted (or I would not type this) - is it possible that this is some strange behavior when mounting something into an encrypted home?

Comment: btw: `/` is as `/dev/disk/by-uuid/d8e94b7d-3de9-4cee-9ce6-1040e5e2f534 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0` in `/proc/mounts` - that's why you don't see it in the `grep`

Comment: I guess this happens if you start with windows, install linux, fry your f***ing windows bootloader with grub2, fix the damn windows and fry it again till you lose your temper and delete the horrible abomination

Comment: now here comes the strange thing: I just change the mount-points to `/mnt/Coding` (and similar) rebooted and everything is fine ?!?

Comment: ... my very best guess: somehow there was something **in** the mount-points (something different than what's on the disk/partition I mounted from - maybe `lost+found`?) and this fucked up everything ... does this make sense?

Comment: I guess I go with symlinks to the folders for now ... **is this a good idea**?

Answer (score 0):

I still have no clue what happened in the first place but I finally managed to get a reasonable solution (for me):

- I remapped the partitions to subpaths in `/mnt`
- I moved the date from my home-folders into the corresponding `/mnt` folders
- I deleted the folders in home
- I put symlinks to `/mnt/..` into my `~`

---

I suspect that somehow the target-folders where not empty at some point and the `mount` failed therefore - or that it's not working with an encrypted home (maybe I should not have let the default-option here on system setup)

Thanks for your help.